# Multiprocessing on large pandas dataframe is suddenly slow

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-zip

I am attempting to use multiprocessing.Pool.starmap to add a new column to my pandas data frame, based on the value of a few other columns, with the following code:

```
def my_func(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    if pd.isna(b) or b == 0 or a == b:
        return c * f
    else:
        return e - d

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(my_func, zip(df["a"], df["b"], df["c"], df["d"], df["e"], repeat(12)))

df["new_col"] = results
```

Running this code with a data frame with 200.000 rows works perfectly fine and takes less than 5 seconds. Trying it again with 2.000.000 rows it seems to be stuck and never finishing. The columns a & b are strings and c,d,e are float in case that matters.

Looking at the CPU utilization it also seems that they are barely working.

Can anyone advise on why this would happen / how to improve the solutions runtime?

UPDATE: Switched to pandarallel with df.parallel_apply(lambda row: my_func(...), axis=1) instead of multiprocessing.Pool

Comment: Please, add a print function to trace your stages in the for loop. After that you may know more about the reason.

Comment: Distributing dataframe columns between processes is not free: inter-process communication (IPC) is generally rather slow. The computation should be intensive enough to hide the overhead of IPC, which is not the case here. Besides this, please check the amount of RAM used.

Comment: @JérômeRichard RAM usage seems non-problematic at ~8GB (lots of RAM to spare). While watching RAM usage I also noticed very low CPU usage specifically during this part of the code. CPUs are sitting at 0.1% - 2.0% usage when they should be working close to 100%. Could this be due to massive IPC overhead?

Comment: Ok. AFAIK, IPC should be seen as CPU work (visible from the user-side). CPU inactivity is generally due to I/Os (including memory swapping, program code fetches, high latency possibly combined with a old HDD) or waits (locks, waiting for a process to finish, etc.). Thus, this is surprising the CPU is not used if memory/swap is not the issue.

Comment: Very strange.. 
I managed to get around the issue now by switching to pandarallel and using df.parallel_apply(lambda row: my_func(...), axis=1). Now all cores are properly utilized and the whole task runs through in a few minutes.
Thanks for the help!